# C#. Распарсить текст и расфасовать слова из него в соответствии с характеристиками

Tags: c#, linq, парсер, работа-с-текстом

Есть файл word.txt, содержание которого(часть файла, всех строк таких 100 тыс.):

```
mersedes тип:автомобиль привод:задний   цвет:серый
audi     тип:автомобиль привод:передний цвет:серый
honda_b5 тип:мотоцикл   привод:передний цвет:синий
творог   тип:еда        цвет:белый
грибы    тип:еда        цвет:белый
bentley  тип:автомобиль привод:задний   цвет:красный

в этом файле:
        имя:            bentley 
        характеристики: тип:автомобиль привод:задний цвет:красный
```

Если "имя" с одной характеристикой два раза повторяется, то перед вторым именем ставим символ ";".

Задание: анализировать(искать слова) введенную строку и в соответствии с характеристиками ставить ;

Мой вариант алгоритма(не исключаю, что быдлокодерский):

1ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ. Пример(введенная строка): "mersedes audi honda_b5. творог bentley грибы.". Помещаем слово mersedes и audi в один массив с именем тип_автомобиль_цвет_серый, и так как они относятся к одному массиву, то ставим перед вторым словом(audi) из массива с именем тип_автомобиль_цвет_серый символ ";" -- получаем текст "mersedes; audi honda_b5. творог bentley грибы."

2ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ. У нас уже есть строка с проверенным первым предложением "mersedes; audi honda_b5. творог bentley грибы.", проверяем второе предложение "творог bentley грибы.", так как встречаетя два слова -- творог и грибы -- с одной характеристикой(тип:еда цвет:белый) и относятся к одному массиву с именем тип_еда_цвет_белый, то перед вторым словом "грибы" ставим ";" 
и получаем итоговую строку "mersedes; audi honda_b5. творог bentley; грибы."

Вариант кода для осуществления поиска в файле:

Num.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Num
    {
        private const string PATH_TO_FILE = "word.txt";
        private HashSet<string> numbers;

        public Num()
        {
            var fromFile = File.ReadAllLines(PATH_TO_FILE);
            numbers = new HashSet<string>(fromFile, new CardComparer());
        }

        public bool Contains(string value)
        {
            return numbers.Contains(value);
        }
    }

    public class CardComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
    {
        public bool Equals(string x, string y)
        {
            return x.StartsWith(y) || y.StartsWith(x);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(string obj)
        {
            int index = obj.IndexOf(' ');
            return index > 0 ? obj.Remove(index).GetHashCode() : obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

==========================================

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            string word = "способ";

            var num = new Num();
            Console.WriteLine(num.Contains(word));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

=========================================================================

Буду очень признателен за помощь, так как у самого ничего не получается, не первый день сижу уже над этим. Язык C#, но если напишите на чем-то похожем, перепишу. Читал, что это как-то с помощью LINQ просто не сложно делается, но как не понял.

Comment: @Bulson а никто не заставлял кого-то **за кого-то решать**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский может и так, но под видом вопроса было выставлено задание, кто-то прошел мимо, а кто-то потратил время и помог. А я не люблю людей, которые только берут, но ничего в ответ не отдают.

Comment: @Bulson ну смотрите: комментарий даже сказать спасибо можно писать только от 50 баллов http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment (не считая коммента под своим собственным вопросом)...у ТС их нет........ голосовать ЗА ответ/вопрос после 15 баллов http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up  .... у автора их, опять же, нет............ галочку ставить если ответ помог.....но с чего вы взяли, что ответ помог? Так что нападки излишни

Comment: Из описания ничего не понятно...если внятно опишите что хотите сделать, то вам помогут разобраться.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "... галочку ставить если ответ помог.....но с чего вы взяли, что ответ помог?" -прочитал вопрос и ответ, и сделал вывод.

Comment: @Bulson если что-то валяется в грязи как свинья и хрюкает как свинья, еще не значит, что это и есть свинья..... точно также и с ответом - если по-вашему мнению он неплох и что-то описывает еще не значит что тот действительно подошел и помог.......в общем, стоит слегка подождать, кмк, всё-таки мало баллов у ТС и вопросов не 50 штук чтобы делать такие серьезные выводы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хорошо, вопрос восстановили, мне вы объяснили кто я, успокойтесь, ради бога.

Comment: Прочитать файл построчно, для каждой строки отделить первое слово, а остаток разбить при помощи [string.Spit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -- начала пробелом, а внутри на пары разделённые через двоеточие. Дальше разбирайся сам, подсказок более чем предостаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для эксперимента берем файл с таким содержимым:

```
mersedes тип:автомобиль привод:задний цвет:серый
audi тип:автомобиль привод:передний цвет:серый
honda_b5 тип:мотоцикл привод:передний цвет:синий
жигули тип:автомобиль привод:задний цвет:серый
творог тип:еда цвет:белый
bentley тип:автомобиль привод:задний цвет:красный
```

Создаем класс

```
class Thing : IEquatable<Thing>
{
    //ctor
    public Thing()
    {
        KeyStringType = "тип";
        KeyStringDrive = "привод";
        KeyStringColor = "цвет";
    }

    public string KeyStringType { get; private set; }
    public string KeyStringDrive { get; private set; }
    public string KeyStringColor { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Drive { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    //реализация интерфейса поможет нам использовать сравнение объектов между соб.
    public bool Equals(Thing other)
    {
        //считаем равными, если равны все свойства за исключ. Name
        return this.Type == other.Type
            && this.Drive == other.Drive
            && this.Color == other.Color;
    }
}
```

Работаем так:

```
class Program
{
    //файл скопирован в проект, свойства имеет: Content, Copy Always
    private const string _fileName = "TextFile.txt"; 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //
        string pathToFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, _fileName);

        //коллекция куда распарсим файл
        List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();
        Thing thing;
        //Читаем разбираем файл
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(pathToFile))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                thing = ParseLine(line);
                things.Add(thing);
            }
        }

        //проверочная строка
        string inputLine = "mersedes жигули audi honda_b5 творог bentley творог";

        //на сколько я смог понять задачу из описания
        string output = AnalyzeInputLine(inputLine, things); 

        Console.WriteLine(output);
        //на выходе получаем: mersedes; жигули audi honda_b5 творог bentley творог

        Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Вспомогательные методы

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Разбор текстовой строки и создание экземпляра Thing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="line">входная строка</param>
    /// <returns>экземпляр Thing</returns>
    private static Thing ParseLine(string line)
    {
        var parts = line.Split().ToList();

        Thing result = new Thing();
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            if (part.StartsWith(result.KeyStringType))
            {
                result.Type = part.Remove(0, result.KeyStringType.Length + 1);
            }
            else if (part.StartsWith(result.KeyStringDrive))
            {
                result.Drive = part.Remove(0, result.KeyStringDrive.Length + 1);
            }
            else if (part.StartsWith(result.KeyStringColor))
            {
                result.Color = part.Remove(0, result.KeyStringColor.Length + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Name = part;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Изменяет входную строку: ставит знак ";"
    /// перед вторым появлением объекта равного первому
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputLine">входная строка</param>
    /// <param name="things">коллекция рабочих объектов</param>
    /// <returns>новая строка</returns>
    private static string AnalyzeInputLine(string inputLine, List<Thing> things)
    {
        List<string> inputs = inputLine.Split().ToList();

        //для сборки выходной строки
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        Thing sample = null;
        Thing current = null;
        bool isFirst = true;
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            current = things.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == input);
            if (isFirst)
            {
                sample = current;
                result.Append(input);
                isFirst = false;
                continue;
            }
            //если совсем не нашлось
            if (current == null)
            {
                result.Append(" " + input);
                continue;
            }
            //если такая же
            if (current.Equals(sample))
            {
                result.Append("; " + input);
                continue;
            }
            //если другая
            sample = current;
            result.Append(" " + input);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

**P.S изменения после уточнения вопроса**

Нам дополнительно понадобится класс сравнения

```
class ThingComparer : IEqualityComparer<Thing>
{
    public bool Equals(Thing x, Thing y)
    {
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Thing obj)
    {
        int hashType = 0;
        int hashDrive = 0;
        int hashColor = 0;

        if (obj.Type != null)
        {
            hashType = obj.Type.GetHashCode();
        }
        if (obj.Drive != null)
        {
            hashDrive = obj.Drive.GetHashCode();
        }
        if (obj.Color != null)
        {
            hashColor = obj.Color.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hashType * 13
                ^ hashDrive
                ^ hashColor;
    }
}
```

Обновленный метод для построения строки с выделением слов знаком двоеточия

```
private static string AnalizeInputLine1(string inputLine, List<Thing> things)
    {
        //делим на предложения по знаку точки
        List<string> sentences = inputLine.Split('.').ToList();
        //избавляемся от пустых предложений
        sentences.Remove("");

        List<string> allWords = new List<string>(); //общая коллекция слов
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> sentencesAndWords =
                                new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();//соотнесение
        foreach (var sentence in sentences)
        {
            //делим предложение на слова
            List<string> wordsSent = sentence.Split().ToList();
            //избавляемся от пустых
            wordsSent.Remove("");

            //собираем слова в общий накопитель
            allWords.AddRange(wordsSent);

            //добавляем в соотнесение
            sentencesAndWords.Add(sentence, wordsSent);

        }


        //находим элементы из списка файла соответствующие словам в строке
        var fileSameThings = (from thing in things
                              from word in allWords
                              where thing.Name == word
                              select thing).ToList();

        //удаляем однотипные (повторяющиеся на основании равенства всех свойств за искл. Name)
        var fileSameDists = fileSameThings.Distinct(new ThingComparer()).ToList();

        //определяем группу слов, кот. нужно выделить
        var mustToSelectWords = fileSameThings.Except(fileSameDists).ToList();

        //для сборки выходной строки
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        bool isFirst = true;
        foreach (var sent in sentencesAndWords)
        {
            foreach (var word in sent.Value)
            {
                //первое слово в предложении
                if (isFirst)
                {
                    //если слово есть в группе выделяемых
                    if (mustToSelectWords.Any(w => w.Name == word))
                    {
                        result.Append(word + ";");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Append(word);
                    }

                    isFirst = false;
                    continue;
                }

                //если слово есть в группе выделяемых
                if (mustToSelectWords.Any(w => w.Name == word))
                {
                    result.Append(" " + word + ";");
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Append(" " + word);
                }
            }
            isFirst = true;
            result.Append(". ");
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

передаем в метод строку:

```
//проверочная строка
string inputLine = "mersedes жигули honda_b5. жигули bentley грибы.";
```

получаем

```
mersedes жигули; honda_b5. жигули; bentley грибы.
```

Выделены "жигули", т.к. только у них совпадают с мерседесом все свойства, кроме Name. Путем изменения класса сравнения можно изменить то, какие объекты будут выделены знаком.

Comment: Пока писал ответ, вопрос был изменен - нужно менять AnalyzeInputLine()

Comment: Да, я как раз смотрю ваше решение, спасибо, что сами и откликнулись. Изменил описание на более подробное -- пошагово, так как первоначальное ТЗ вводило в заблуждение. 

Ваше решение отлично написано и работает, но выполняет немного не ту задачу. Если есть свободные 10 минут, то ваша помощь будет очень кстати, если нет, то я пошел дальше сходить с ума :)

Comment: @НикаНайтли я не понимаю, что на выходе вы хотите получить: новый файл с этими же строками, но с проставленными точками с запятой или что? Напишите яснее: имею то-то, в результате должно быть то-то.

Comment: Нет, новый файл не нужен. Просто выводим новую строку. Имеем текстовую строку без точки с запятой, а получить нужно с точками с запятой в местах, где необходимо. 
Было: `"mersedes audi honda_b5. творог bentley грибы."`
Стало: `"mersedes; audi honda_b5. творог bentley; грибы."`

Но имеем ввиду, что в этом тексте два предложения(может быть больше). То есть чтобы не получилось строки  `"mersedes; audi honda_b5. ;mersedes творог bentley; грибы."`(обратите внимание на символ перед вторым словом mersedes) так как слово mersedes в новом предложении не относится к первому предложению.

Comment: Видимо, задача оказалась чуть сложнее, чем казалось )

Comment: Вы пишите , что было: `"mersedes audi honda_b5. творог bentley грибы." ` а должно стать `"mersedes; audi honda_b5. творог bentley; грибы."` Почему у первого слова mersedes должна быть `;` если у audi привод:передний , т.е. это другая сущность?

Comment: @НикаНайтли Не знаю, наверное, дополнительный вариант вас должен устроить.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я внес минимальные поправки и получил что нужно. Огромное спасибо за проделанную работу.

Comment: @НикаНайтли You're welcome.